# Multiprocessing and lists

Tags: python, list, multiprocessing

I have been trying to optimise my code using the multiprocessing module, but I think I have fallen for the trap of premature optimization.

For example, when running this code:

```
num = 1000000
l = mp.Manager().list()
for i in range(num):
    l.append(i)
l_ = Counter(l)
```

It takes several times longer than this:

```
num = 1000000
l = []
for i in range(num):
    l.append(i)
l_ = Counter(l)
```

What is the reason the multiprocessing list is slower than regular lists? And are there ways to make them as efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Shared memroy data structures](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) are meant to be shared between processes. To synchronize accesses, they need to be locked. On the other hand, a `list` (`[]`) does not require a lock.

**With / without locking** makes a difference.